# I wanted to fetch "Custom Search Style" dimension from Google Adsense

Tags: adsense, adsense-api

In the dimension and metrics link:
https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/metrics-dimensions

I couldn't.find anything related to Style ID or Style name.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation page you linked has all of the available API dimensions. Unfortunately, Style ID and Style Name are not available.